# Windows route add error

Tags: route

Windows Server 2003 Standard Edition

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>route print

## IPv4 Route Table

Interface List
0x1 ........................... MS TCP Loopback interface
0x10003 ...00 14 22 10 7f ea ...... Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection #2

## 0x10004 ...00 14 22 10 7f e9 ...... Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Network Connection

===========================================================================

Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0   192.168.12.199    192.168.12.39     10
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1      1
     192.168.12.0    255.255.255.0    192.168.12.39    192.168.12.39     10
    192.168.12.39  255.255.255.255        127.0.0.1        127.0.0.1     10
   192.168.12.255  255.255.255.255    192.168.12.39    192.168.12.39     10
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0    192.168.12.39    192.168.12.39     10
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255    192.168.12.39            10003      1
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255    192.168.12.39    192.168.12.39      1
Default Gateway:    192.168.12.199
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>route -p add x.x.x.x mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.96.199
The route addition failed: Either the interface index is wrong or the gateway do
es not lie on the same network as the interface. Check the IP Address Table for
the machine.

I can't add in above routing. Expert, can help pls?

Answer (score 2):

C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator>route -p add x.x.x.x mask 255.255.255.255 **192.168.96.199**
 The route addition failed: Either the interface index is wrong or **the gateway does not lie on the same network as the interface**. Check the IP Address Table for the machine.

Your host is on the 192.168.12.0 subnet but the gateway address for the route you're trying to add is on the 192.168.96.x subnet, which is not local to your host. The gateway address has to be local to (on the same subnet as) your host.